# I am trying to customize my y-axis with dates. How do I remove this gap between dates in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
DATA <- data.frame(DATA$CASES_CF,DATA$Date2)
library(ggplot2)
ddd <- c("2020-01-30","2020-02-02","2020-02-03","2020-02-10","2020-03-01","2020-03-03","2020-03-04","2020-03-05","2020-03-06","2020-03-07","2020-03-08","2020-03-09","2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12","2020-03-13","2020-03-14","2020-03-15","2020-03-16","2020-03-17","2020-03-18")
ddd <- as.Date(ddd)
ddd

draw <-  ggplot(DATA,aes(CASES_CF,DATA$Date2,colour=STATE))+scale_y_date(breaks=ddd)
```

There is a big gap after 2020-03-01 I don't want that. Although breaks have done what I wanted but these gaps how do I remove these gaps? I have tried all the arguments scale_y_date has but no luck. Can anyone help me with this? 
[image]

Comment: For time series, _usually_ the x-axis will show the date and the y-axis will contain the information (here count). Don't you want to know that there were certain gaps in the data? This can be useful knowledge. If you __really__ want to remove the gaps, one ways is to change the dates into factors.

Comment: Yes, there are gaps. I representing confirmed cases of COV-19.Can I at lease display with any label in the graph that there are no cases between these gaps.

Comment: Yes - that's what I would do. Or you can show _cumulative cases_, then days with no case will appear as a straight line.

Comment: Actually I have shown half of my code here. I have written gganimate code after ggplot code and I want to animate this after I figure this out any idea how should I work?

Comment: Just focus on one question per page/post. And if you `dput` the data, you'll get more help. ;)

Comment: So that I understand ... you explicitly set the breaks for the y-axis on a continuous (well, near-continuous) scale, and you don't like the space between the values? Yes, `factor` is perhaps the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your data, I can't reproduce the exact image you want, but if you leave the dates as character you can remove the extra space in the graph. With some dummy data:

```
DATA <- data.frame(CASES_CF = 1:21, 
                   Date = c("2020-01-30","2020-02-02","2020-02-03","2020-02-10",
                            "2020-03-01","2020-03-03","2020-03-04","2020-03-05",
                            "2020-03-06","2020-03-07","2020-03-08","2020-03-09",
                            "2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12","2020-03-13",
                            "2020-03-14","2020-03-15","2020-03-16","2020-03-17",
                            "2020-03-18"))

ddd <- c("2020-01-30","2020-02-02","2020-02-03","2020-02-10","2020-03-01","2020-03-03",
         "2020-03-04","2020-03-05","2020-03-06","2020-03-07","2020-03-08","2020-03-09",
         "2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12","2020-03-13","2020-03-14","2020-03-15",
         "2020-03-16","2020-03-17","2020-03-18")

ddd <- factor(ddd)
ddd

ggplot(DATA, aes(CASES_CF, Date)) + scale_y_discrete(breaks = ddd) + geom_point()
```

[image]

If you decide to covert the date format into something different (e.g. 18 Mar 20), you may be better off converting to factor and setting your levels with that function.